# Concatenate two string letter by letter in mips

Tags: string, concatenation, mips

Hi ive been trying to concatenate to strings input is two strings: "john" and "la" and it should print "lala" instead it prints "llll" and I cant fix it.

```
.data  
texto:  .asciiz "john"
cifra:  .asciiz "la"
.text

la $a0,texto  #pass address of str1
la $a1,cifra  #pass address of str2

jal conc
conc:
add $t1,$zero,$a0
add $t2,$zero,$a1


loop:
lb $t3($t1)  
lb $t4($t2) 
lbu $t4,0($a1)  
sb $t4, 0($a1)

beq $t3, $zero, end
nop
move $a0,$t4
li   $v0, 11
syscall
addi $t1, $t1, 1
addi $t2,$t2, 1
j loop

end:
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you want to merge the two strings on a char-by-char basis, the correct output is `jloahn`

Your code wouldn't even assemble. And, it would only utilize one of the two strings. I've provided two versions. One is annotated with the bugs. The other is the fully corrected version [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup].

The annotated version:

```
    .data
texto:      .asciiz     "john"
cifra:      .asciiz     "la"
    .text

    la      $a0,texto               # pass address of str1
    la      $a1,cifra               # pass address of str2

    jal     conc

    # BUG: no exit program
    li      $v0,10
    syscall

conc:
    add     $t1,$zero,$a0
    add     $t2,$zero,$a1

loop:
    # BUG: these won't even assemble
    ###lb       $t3($t1)
    ###lb       $t4($t2)

    lb      $t3,0($t1)
    lb      $t4,0($t2)

    # BUG: these fetch from $a1 which is never incremented -- in other words,
    # t4 will always get the same first char (i.e. "l")
    ###lbu      $t4,0($a1)
    ###sb       $t4,0($a1)

    beq     $t3,$zero,end
    nop

    # output next char
    # BUG: this only outputs chars from one string
    move    $a0,$t4
    li      $v0,11
    syscall

    addi    $t1,$t1,1
    addi    $t2,$t2,1
    j       loop

end:
    jr      $ra
```

The cleaned up and corrected version:

```
    .data
texto:      .asciiz     "john"
cifra:      .asciiz     "la"
out:        .space      80

    .text

    la      $a0,out                 # get address of output

    la      $a1,texto               # pass address of str1
    la      $a2,cifra               # pass address of str2
    jal     conc

    # output the concatenated string
    la      $a0,out
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    # BUG: no exit program
    li      $v0,10
    syscall

# conc -- concatenate strings char-by-char
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- output pointer
#   a1 -- pointer to string to concatenate
#   a2 -- pointer to string to concatenate
conc:
    lb      $t1,0($a1)              # get string char
    beqz    $t1,conc_no1st          # EOS? if yes, skip
    addi    $a1,$a1,1               # advance 1st source pointer
    sb      $t1,0($a0)              # add to output
    addi    $a0,$a0,1               # advance output pointer

conc_no1st:
    lb      $t2,0($a2)              # add to output
    beqz    $t2,conc_no2nd          # EOS? if yes, skip
    addi    $a2,$a2,1               # advance 2nd source pointer
    sb      $t2,0($a0)              # add to output
    addi    $a0,$a0,1               # advance output pointer

conc_no2nd:
    or      $t1,$t1,$t2             # both chars EOS?
    bnez    $t1,conc                # no, loop

    sb      $zero,0($a0)            # store final EOS
    jr      $ra
```

Comment: The output that i wanted was "lalal" but thanks for the tip

Comment: The `jloahn` is based upon your question's title [_"concatenate two strings letter by letter"_] from the two strings `john` and `la`. A simple word concat would be `johnla`. So, I'm not sure how you get from the _two_ strings to something that only repeats the second string (i.e. `lalal`) and has length 5 with input lengths of 4 and 2 respectively. So, it might be helpful for you to edit your question to clarify this as it isn't immediately apparent [to me, at least] what algorithm is to be used to combine the two input strings and produce the `lalal` output.